# How to Single installation of two folders in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I am having two folders line "en" and "th". Both are different folders i need to run the both folders in single installation using react and i need to redirect the pages like below

```
http://example.com/en/<somepage>   (English)
http://example.com/th/<somepage>   (Thailand)
```

Comment: Look into a router for react, such as the excellent react-router: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router

Comment: what does "single installation" mean to you? is running two separate commands in a single script good enough?

Comment: @azium I need to run the both projects in single command. We going to run the both in a single app.

Comment: ok so... run both commands in the same script?

Comment: @azium. Yes. Like "Apple" website https://www.apple.com.